# Add add-to-cart button in Shopify Collections

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have a problem with the ENVY template. This template does not have support for adding a shopping cart button in the collections that are located in the home. before this I have decided to add my own code in the area where these products are shown, but when pressing the button add to cart, it sends me to an error page with the message **"Parameter Missing or Invalid: Required parameter missing or invalid: items" my codes are as follows:**

```
 function instantBuy(){
     var $ = jQuery;

   var formParams = $('form.cart').serialize();
     $.ajax({
      url: "/cart/add",
      type: "post",
      data: formParams,
      success: function(){ 
       window.location.href = "/checkout";
      },
      error: function(){
      }
     })
 }
```

**form code**

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants" id="product-actions-{{ product.id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="variantId" value="{{ product.variants[0].id }}" />
<button class="button buynow-btn" title="Buy" onClick="instantBuy()"><span>Buy now</span></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a request to the /cart/add has to be sent "id" arguments.
At the moment you are sending "variantId" instead of "id".

Also in your JavaScript there is no preventDefault to preserver the browser to send the request.

In another hand, this can be done without JavaScript.

Here is the updated code:

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants" id="product-actions-{{ liquidObject.id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ liquidObject.variants[0].id }}" />
<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/checkout" />
<button class="button buynow-btn" title="Buy"><span>Buy now</span></button>
</form>
```

Also added a "return_to" hidden field, which will redirect the user directly to checkout when hits the button

Comment: I continue with the same problem. Copy image of the error and where to place the code https://ibb.co/Y0CfCSW - https://ibb.co/CzJhTP1

Comment: I've updated the code.
Have to be used liquidObject variable instead of product.

Comment: Great, but this code is sending it to the payment page and I need you to send it to the cart drawer

Comment: Jst change "return_to" value to the URL that you want the user to be redirected to.
If you want to redirect them to cart just replace /checkout with /cart.

Comment: how can I get the path of a cart drawer to replace it with checkout?

Comment: @kamenarov That was awesome. THANK YOU VERY MUCH for this snippet! I've implemented it (with a modification to the return_to page), but it works like a charm.
I would like to add though that when I implemented this, I also checked if the item was in stock.. which actually was some code that I found on the page I implemented this.. right underneath where I put the code, so that took care of that as well.

Comment: I assume you can also make this a link, instead of a form...?